# Dragging zoomed in image in Canvas2D HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas where I draw frames of a video as images, like this:

```
ctxVideo.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvasVideo.width * scale, canvasVideo.height * scale);
```

the initial scale is 1.0 and it changes as the user clicks on the zoom in/out buttons, like this:

```
document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  scale /= scaleMultiplier;
}, false);

document.getElementById("minus").addEventListener("click", function () {
   scale *= scaleMultiplier;
   if (scale < 1.0) {
    scale = 1.0;
 }
}, false);
```

This works just fine and it zooms in/out correctly, but it zooms towards the top left edge of the canvas. So, I need to add the functionality of dragging so that the user can see other parts of the zoomed in image.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Translate the middle of the canvas to 0,0 Apply the zoom, translate the canvas back again. Substitute the middle of the canvas for the coordinates of any particular area of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way probably would be using a small js-libary like [pan-zoom](https://github.com/timmywil/panzoom). Otherwise, you need to calculate all offsets and scales by yourself.